# match two sets of arrays containing rgb color values using if/else

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

So I can create an array with rgb color values such as:

var atomArr = ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];

With out going into details, I can even assign an object's background-color with a value from the array.

So why can't I take two similar arrays and check if both of them match (ordered match not necessary, but both arrays must contain the same values)?

In the example below, both arrays have the exact same values (not in order), but always triggers false.

```js
var h2o = ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
function Check(A) {
    var atomArr = ['rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
    var i, j;
    var totalmatches = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < atomArr.length; i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
      if (atomArr[i] === A[j]) {
       totalmatches++;
      }
     }
    }
    if (totalmatches == 3) {
     console.log("true");
    } else {
     console.log("false");
    }
}

Check(h2o);
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Total matches gave you 5. You need a different algorithm to consider the repetitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses the function `reduce` to sum matches.

```js
var h2o = ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
function Check(A) {
    var atomArr = ['rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
    var checked = true;
    A.forEach((r) => {
      if (!checked) return;
      
      var count = A.reduce((a, c) => a + (c === r ? 1 : 0), 0);
      var outerCount = atomArr.reduce((a, c) => a + (c === r ? 1 : 0), 0);
      
      checked = checked && count === outerCount;
    });
    
    console.log(checked);
}

Check(h2o);
```

## `for-loop`

```js
var h2o = ['rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
function Check(A) {
    var atomArr = ['rgb(255, 34, 0)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 34, 0)'];
    var checked = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
      if (!checked) break;
      
      var r = A[i];
      var count = A.reduce((a, c) => a + (c === r ? 1 : 0), 0);
      var outerCount = atomArr.reduce((a, c) => a + (c === r ? 1 : 0), 0);
      
      checked = checked && count === outerCount;
    };
    
    console.log(checked);
}

Check(h2o);
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you for pointing me to the reduce method.  After doing a little research, this approach makes sense.

Comment: Quick question @Ele.  I would like to use your solution multiple times for different color combinations.  I've tried to reset/clear all the variables from your solution in many different ways, but no matter what, "count" and especially "outerCount" increment higher every time it's initiated, giving me an incorrect answer.  Unfortunately I'm not super skilled at this level of shorthand JS syntax. How do I reset/clear this function before it is called again with a different set of arrays?

Comment: @themandoz can you share how you’re using this approach?  As you can see, the function `Check` is always using the same inner Array.  Share how you’re using to help you.

Comment: so I simplified my model in preparation to show you the issue in CodePen, but then found your code is working as expected.  So apparently I need to further investigate my script and see where things are falling apart. Will let you know if I am unable to figure it out.  Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: I found my error and your solution now works great! Thanks again!